# Installing xdebug on ubuntu 14.04 not creating xdebug.ini file

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, xdebug, php

I've been trying to install xdebug for php5-fpm on my vagrant box with `sudo apt-get php5-xdebug`
However, I was not able to find any xdebug.ini file created in `/etc/php5/fpm/conf.d` or `/etc/php5/mods-available` for that matter and every google search suggests there should be the xdebug.ini files being created there. Any suggestions on where this went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:

It turned out that I tried installing php5-xdebug before and manually removed the init file myself. When using `apt-get remove php5-xdebug`, it only removes the package but not the configuration files, so  the next `apt-get install php5-xdebug` will assume the .ini files are already there and won't try to create new ones. The issue is solved with --purge parameters in apt-get remove. `sudo apt-get --purge remove php5-xdebug` and then install the package again.